# The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction In Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am new in orchard CMS, I am integrating my own application in orchard CMS. I have create a edmx file then  I have created an Action to Display the records,  But it give me ERROR THAT  "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction".

Here is a code

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
                       return View(_db.tblNameTests.ToList());
        }
in view the code is:

@model List

Aboutus

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

Id
        
        
            Name
        
    

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    

        

            @item.id 
        
        @item.name

        
    
}

Is I am missing some thing?
Waiting for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 2):

You need to opt out of Orchard's ambient transaction. See: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/17291